# Chrome and Firefox will not stop loading Google Docs

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-docs

When I view any Google Docs document in Chrome, the tab will not stop loading.  It loads, stops for a second, then starts loading again and as far as I can tell does not stop.  The "x" button does not stop the process (and sometimes is not even available despite the loading icon), nor does Escape, and reloading does not help.  This also happens in Firefox.

The animated "loading" icon on the tab and the "Waiting for docs.google.com"/"Transferring data from google.com" status messages are driving me nuts.  Does anyone know how to stop this in either browser (preferably Chrome)?  I don't want to have to resort to IE every time I write.

Comment: Do you have any software like AdBlock Plus installed (or entries in /drivers/etc/hosts file)? If so, try disabling it temporarily or whitelisting `docs.google.com` domain and see if it improves anything.

Comment: Are you on a slow internet connection? This happens on slow connections. Does it only happens to Google Docs or other websites too?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `docs.google.com` to the AddPlus whitelist does the trick.

Comment: From comment by @jakub.g

Comment: Disabling Adblock entirely (via Settings -> Extensions) had no effect. The damn spreadsheet keeps auto-reloading. In years of Google Docs-ing (or is it Drive now?), I've never seen this.